# How do I pass selected items in MVC4 EF5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, listbox, many-to-many

I am new to MVC and would appreciate any advice. I have several models/tables that work together. The trouble I am having is with a many-to-many relationship. What I want is to have a listbox that a user can multiselect from and pass those values to save in join table, while saving the primary entry to another table.

My models:

```
    public class Card
    {
        public virtual int CardID { get; set; }
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
        //A bunch of properties...
        //Drop Down Lists
        public int RarityID { get; set; }
        public virtual Rarity Rarity { get; set; }
        public int MainTypeID { get; set; }
        public virtual MainType MainType { get; set; }
        public int CardSetID { get; set; }
        public virtual CardSet CardSet { get; set; }
        public int SubTypeID { get; set; }
        public virtual SubType SubType { get; set; }
        public virtual string AdditionalType { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<CardAbility> Abilities { get; set; }
        public virtual int[] SelectedAbilities { get; set; }
    }
    public class Ability
    {
        public virtual int AbilityID { get; set; }
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<CardAbility> Cards { get; set; }
}

public class CardAbility
    {
        public int CardAbilityID { get; set; }
        public virtual Ability Ability { get; set; }
        public int AbilityID { get; set; }
        public virtual Card Card { get; set; }
        public int CardID { get; set; }
    }
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.RarityID = new SelectList(db.Rarities, "RarityID", "Title");
            ViewBag.MainTypeID = new SelectList(db.MainTypes, "MainTypeID", "Title");
            ViewBag.CardSetID = new SelectList(db.CardSets, "CardSetID", "Title");
            ViewBag.SubTypeID = new SelectList(db.SubTypes, "SubTypeID", "Title");
            ViewBag.Abilities = new MultiSelectList(db.Abilities, "AbilityID", "Title");
            return View();
        }
        // POST: /Card/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Card card)
        //[ModelBinder(typeof(CardBinder1))]
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Cards.Add(card);
                db.SaveChanges();

                foreach (var items in card.SelectedAbilities)
                {
                    var obj = new CardAbility() { AbilityID = items, CardID = card.CardID };
                    db.CardAbilities.Add(obj);
                }

                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.RarityID = new SelectList(db.Rarities, "RarityID", "Title", card.RarityID);
            ViewBag.MainTypeID = new SelectList(db.MainTypes, "MainTypeID", "Title", card.MainTypeID);
            ViewBag.CardSetID = new SelectList(db.CardSets, "CardSetID", "Title", card.CardSetID);
            ViewBag.SubTypeID = new SelectList(db.SubTypes, "SubTypeID", "Title", card.SubTypeID);
            ViewBag.Abilities = new MultiSelectList(db.Abilities, "AbilityID", "Title");
            return View(card);
```

My Create View:

```
model MTG.Models.Card

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Card</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
         <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Abilities")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Abilities, (ViewBag.AbilityID as MultiSelectList))
                       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Abilities)
        </div>
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RarityID, "Rarity")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("RarityID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RarityID)
        </div>
// A lot more fields...
 <p>
            &lt;input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

My DBContext:

```
public DbSet&lt;Ability&gt; Abilities { get; set; }
        public DbSet&lt;Rarity&gt; Rarities { get; set; }
        public DbSet&lt;CardSet&gt; CardSets { get; set; }
        public DbSet&lt;MainType&gt; MainTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet&lt;SubType&gt; SubTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet&lt;Card&gt; Cards { get; set; }
        public DbSet&lt;CardAbility&gt; CardAbilities { get; set; }

        public class AbilitiesToCardsConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration&lt;CardAbility&gt;
        {
            internal AbilitiesToCardsConfiguration()
            {
                this.HasKey(p =&gt; new { p.AbilityID, p.CardID });
                this.HasRequired(p =&gt; p.Ability)
                    .WithMany(p =&gt; p.Cards)
                    .HasForeignKey(p =&gt; p.AbilityID);
                this.HasRequired(p =&gt; p.Card)
                    .WithMany(r =&gt; r.Abilities)
                    .HasForeignKey(p =&gt; p.CardID);
            }
        }
```

I have been working on this for about 3 days and have done a lot of trial and error from what I have read online. At this point, the create view does display a listbox that is pulling the titles from the Abilities table. When I try to save, I get a validation error "The value "1" is invalid.", where 1 is the ID for that ability. When debugging, I see that the modelstate is invalid and the error is

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'MTG.Models.CardAbility' failed because no type converter can convert between these types.
   at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.ConvertSimpleType(CultureInfo culture, Object value, Type destinationType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.UnwrapPossibleArrayType(CultureInfo culture, Object value, Type destinationType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.ConvertTo(Type type, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.ConvertProviderResult(ModelStateDictionary modelState, String modelStateKey, ValueProviderResult valueProviderResult, Type destinationType)}
```

I know it doesn't like the types and can't convert, but if I try anything else with the listboxfor helper it won't bring in the data and usually crashes before I even get to see the create page. Sorry this is so long, I just wanted to give all the information I could. :) Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a listbox for `SelectedAbilities` instead of `Abilities`:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedAbilities , (ViewBag.AbilityID as MultiSelectList))
```

*By the way you need to do the same for `RarityID` instead of `Rarity`, `MainTypeID` instead of `MainType` and etc.*

Comment: I created a view model and got the attributes to work, Now I am trying to do the same to rarity etc. @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedRarity, Model.RarityList); keeps throwing error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: SelectedRarity should be a simple type like int or string.It can not be a complex object. Also make sure that neither your Model nor Model .RarityList are not nulls.

Comment: I added  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Rarities { get; set; } public int SelectedRarities { get; set; } to my view model and changed my view to @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedRarities, ViewBag.Rarity_ID as SelectList). That is working now.